# Error in PDF VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller, record

I am trying with this code to retrieve the score of year-1 and year -2 and display it on my PDF.

the error I have is: `Unknown property 'Retail_NFT__cStandardController.records'`

=>VisualForce :

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c" renderAs="PDF"    extensions="MyApex_Controller"
applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" title="MyPage">

<div>
   <apex:outputText style="color: #0a5ec3;font-size: 80%;"  value="{0}">
                    <apex:param value="{!MyObject__c.Name}" />
                </apex:outputText>
</div>

<table style=" font-family: 'Helvetica';border-collapse: collapse;width: 90%; margin-top:-40px;border: 1px solid white;">
<tr style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;height:30px; width:100%;">
<td style="border: 1px  white;background-color:#F5F5F5;color:black;">Services</td>
<td style="border: 1px  white;background-color:#F5F5F5;color:black;">{!$Label.Year2}</td>
<td style="border: 1px  white;background-color:#F5F5F5;color:black;">{!$Label.Year1}</td>

</tr>
    
  
     <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="record">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>{!$Label.Result}</strong></td>
            <td><strong style="margin-left:45%;">{!MyApex_Controller.getyear1(record.Id, 2)}%</strong></td>
            <td><strong style="margin-left:50%;">{!MyApex_Controller.getyear1(record.Id, 1)}%</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>

</apex:page>
```

=> Apex :

```
public with sharing class MyApex_Controller {

 List<wrapper> stw = new List<wrapper>();
  public Id RecordId {get;set;}    
 
    private final MyObject__c obj;
    public MyApex_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.obj= (MyObject__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

 public Integer getyear1(id recordId, Integer n) {
 
        Integer lastYear = System.Today().year()-n;


        Id account= [SELECT Compte__c FROM MyObject__c WHERE  id =:recordId LIMIT 1].Compte__c;

        List<AggregateResult> results =[SELECT AVG (score__c) FROM Monde__c WHERE Account_Name__r.id =: account AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c) =: lastYear];  

        Decimal Y = 0;
        if(results[0].get('expr0')!=null) {
            Y = Y + (Decimal) results[0].get('expr0');
        }    

        Integer sumAmountAsInteger = Y.intValue();

        return sumAmountAsInteger;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="record">
```

You don't have a `getRecords`, or `public List<sObject> records { get; set; }`, or some variant, so the compiler is complaining. Perhaps you meant to use `recordSetVar="records"` on `apex:page`, or something else?

---

```
{!MyApex_Controller.getyear1(record.Id, 2)}
```

This syntax isn't supported. You can't pass in parameters to an Apex controller method. You'll need to calculate this data in the constructor. Also, SOQL in a loop is bad, so even if you could, this would be a bad way to do so. Instead, consider something like:

```
public MyApex_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
  // Unit tests fail if you addFields here.
  if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
    stdController.addFields(new String[] { 'Compte__c' });
  }
  this.obj= (MyObject__c)stdController.getRecord();
  Id accountId = this.obj.Compte__c;
  AggregateResult[] results = [
    SELECT 
      AVG(Score__c), CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c)
    FROM 
      Monde__c 
    WHERE 
      Account_Name__c = :accountId AND Date__c = LAST_N_YEARS:3 AND Date__c < THIS_YEAR 
    GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c)
  ];
  // Do something with the results here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a wrapper and it solved my problem , this is the code :

```
    public class wrapper1 {
   public String Service {get;set;}
   public Decimal Y_1 {get;set;}
   public Decimal Y_2 {get;set;}
     
   public wrapper1(String Service, Decimal Y_1, Decimal Y_2){
   this.Service = Service;
   this.Y_2 = Y_2;
   this.Y_1 = Y_1;
   }
      }
     
   public wrapper1 getYears() {
          
           Integer n = 1;
           Integer lastYear = System.Today().year()-n;
             
           Id account = obj.Compte__c;

          List<AggregateResult> results =[SELECT AVG (score__c) FROM Monde__c WHERE Account_Name__r.id =: account AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c) =: lastYear];  

     
   Integer a = 2;
   Integer lastYear2 = System.Today().year()-a;

        List<AggregateResult> results2 =[SELECT AVG (score__c) FROM Monde__c WHERE Account_Name__r.id =: account AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c) =: lastYear2 ];  

     
   Decimal Y = 0;
  
   if(results[0].get('expr0')!=null) {
    Y = Y + (Decimal) results[0].get('expr0');
   }
     
   
     
  Decimal Y2 = 0;
     
   if(results2[0].get('expr0')!=null) {
    Y2 = Y2 + (Decimal) results2[0].get('expr0');
   }
     
   return new wrapper1('', Y, Y2);
       }
```

And for VF :

```
  <apex:repeat value="{!Years}" var="year">
     <tr>
     <td><strong>{!$Label.Result}</strong></td>
     
     <td><strong style="margin-left:45%;">{!year.Y_2}%</strong></td>
     <td><strong style="margin-left:50%;">{!year.Y_1}%</strong></td>
     </tr>
     </apex:repeat>
```